# Alternating series failing the first criteria

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am taking a Calculus course and pretty new here, but I cant find a solution to this problem anywhere.

[image: Do not know how to write math on this site yet, sorry in advance, here is a picture]

The series is obviously alternating, so I want to check if it meets the criteria for the alternating series test. It fails the first criteria, as for small values of **n** it is increasing, and for large **n** it decreases. The divergence test gives the value of the series to be zero as **n** approaches infinity.

How do I go forward determening if the series diverges or converges?

Comment: Remember that the nature of a series does not depend on its first terms.

Comment: It is decreasing, after a few terms (and finitely many terms don't have any impact on convergence).

Comment: Thanks! This was my thought, but since I still rely on my textbook and they didnt specify it, I could not be sure!

Comment: There is also the Ratio Test.

Comment: @OscarLanzi that only works for positive series?

Comment: @luke not at all. The Ratio Test depends only on the absolute values of the terms.